# Accessing Netbeans Code Completion Variable List Programmatically

Tags: java, c++, parsing, netbeans

I have a working educational Java-palette Module for Netbeans that helps first-year students learn the basics of programming without needing to worry so much about syntax.

When a student drags an item from the palette, they get a popup that allows them to fill-in the details of the code to be dropped, such as variable names or values. I have `ComboBoxes` that list all the variables in the document.  For the Java version of the palette, I simply used **JavaParser** to get a list of the variables, method names, classes, etc.

Now, I'm doing a version of this palette for C++ students.  This time around, I'd rather not use JavaParser, javacc, ANTLR, etc as it seems like overkill. NetBeans already has the list I need when you hit `Ctrl+space`, but I can't find a way to access the list from a form. Geertjan has [a great tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/jtextfield_code_completion) on using code completion in a `JEditorPane` 
 which addresses implementing your own code completion provider which brings me back to square one.

And [this page](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Question-about-generating-a-list-of-variables-in-use-at-a-certain-time-td2916905.html) suggests that NetBeans is simply grabbing a list of variables from the debugger stack.  The debugger API doesn't suggest any straight forward methods for asking for a variable list that I could discern.

Any suggestion on using Netbeans APIs to grab a list of variables from a C++ source file, rather than resorting to a parser?